# Is there a way to list automatically the dependencies of my ROS package

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I noticed that I'm able to run my Python nodes even if I didn't report the dependencies properly in `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`. Many things work simply because all the required ROS packages are installed on my computer. Now assume I want to distribute my package, how to make sure that I didn't miss any dependency?
Is there an automatic way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303655/is-there-a-way-to-list-automatically-the-dependencies-of-my-ros-package/) by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-18**:\

> I noticed that I'm able to run my Python nodes even if I didn't report the dependencies properly in `CMakeLists.txt` [..]

For Python nodes, which are not compiled, there are (normally) no build dependencies, so `CMakeLists.txt` is not involved in those cases.

Python pkgs only have run depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two tools that can actually help you with this.

[`roscompile`](https://github.com/DLu/roscompile/blob/master/roscompile/README.md) by @David Lu figures out many issue, also missing dependencies. To quote the ReadMe:

> - Checks for dependencies by looking in the source code, message, service, action and launch files.
> - Inserts build/run/test dependencies into your package.xml
> - Inserts dependencies into your CMakeLists.txt (in both the find_package and catkin_package commands)
> - Sorts lists of dependencies (in both package.xml/CMakeLists.txt)

Also `catkin_lint` helps in setting the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` up correctly. The combination of both tools is pretty powerful. But you should still but some thought into what is going on...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-09-18**:
https://gph.is/2rMkoJZ

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-18**:
"Approved" :-D

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-18**:
Wow, approved by the author... Thanks, that looks handy.